# Flutter Error: Could not find or load main class java.xml.bind

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm just trying to run my first dummy project created with `flutter create myflutterapp`. However, when I try to run that either in Android Studio or through `flutter run` in the command line, I get the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class java.xml.bind`. The virtual emulator is running Android 8.1.